# Does ninject-contrib support Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, prism, ioc-container, ninject

I'm building a Silverlight application with Prism, and we'd like to use NInject.  I've downloaded ninject-contrib to use their NInject bootstrapper, but it doesn't appear to build a Silverlight assembly.  I compiled it myself to Silverlight, but it crashes Visual Studio.

Has anyone already ported ninject-contrib to Silverlight successfully?

Comment: Crashes Visual Studio? What if you try building it just from the command line, w/msbuild - the errors might be helpful in tracking this down

Comment: The source code didn't build a Silverlight library, so I added a new Silverlight library project to the solution, then got it to compile.  In my own project's solution, I added a reference to the compiled assembly and created a custom bootstrapper inheriting from the NInject bootstrapper.  When I debugged my solution, Visual Studio crashed.

I think I'm missing something, and perhaps the ninject-contrib solution can already build an assembly that's tested and works against Silverlight?

Comment: Btw, I downloaded the ninject-contrib source from http://ninject-contrib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk.

Comment: Miguel Midero says there's a project for Silverlight, but I don't see it.

http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/a63adb449c4c3908

Comment: Ah, Miguel was asking if he could submit a patch.  I have no idea whether it has been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use ninject-contrib. There is a download available for Silverlight. You can find it [here](http://ninject.org/download). Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for, but if you would just like to use Ninject for dependency injection in a Silverlight app, this should be all you need.

Comment: Looking back at my original question, I did a poor job of specifying what I was looking for.  Prism applications, whether built for WPF or Silverlight, typically contain a class that bootstraps the application using the particular IoC container.  Ninject-contrib contains a Prism bootstrapper that leverages NInject.  I was attempting to use this bootstrapper, but I found that the Visual Studio solution did not contain a project file that targeted Silverlight...

Comment: What I ended up doing was importing the source code into a Silverlight class library project and making a few small changes to get it to compile.

Next I wrote a few unit tests using a version of NUnit 2.5.1 ported to Silverlight 3: http://wesmcclure.tumblr.com/post/152727000  When I used TestDriven.NET to run unit tests that exercised the bootstrapper, Visual Studio 2008 crashed.

Comment: Since using this combination of tools together (including my own untested "port" of ninject-contrib to SL3) was a very large hack, I probably should have considered an alternate solution before posting to StackOverflow.

What I've ended up doing is to stop using the bootstrapper altogether in unit tests, which is probably a good idea anyway, as you probably don't want your unit tests to be coupled to your application bootstrapping anyway.